# Pagination for a grid with Umbraco

Tags: gridview, pagination, umbraco

I'm new with Umbraco and I'm now working on pagination feature for a page with a grid. I want it to show 4 grid lines in each page. I've been searching for some code snippets to help me but so far couldn't really find any that looks like what I need and to use with grid.

Can anyone help me please? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are you talking about an Umbraco Grid editor, or some  sort of table/area on a template or macro?

Comment: I'm talking about grid editor. I've search for some solutions,but so far the ones I found are deprecated and don't apply to grid editors. Please I really need some help with this. Thank you!

Comment: Anyone? Please really need help with this!

Answer (score 0):

A few things that should help:

The grid is just a MVC view which is rendered and passed the grid data when requested.

If you are looking to handle "paging" as a method of organization, and not as optimization. You could find or write some JS that handles paging of divs. Something that handles tabs would also work. You have full control of the grid render views.

In /Views/Partials/Grid, you could start with bootstrap3.cshtml, make a copy and add change the structure to meet your requirements, keeping in mind how rows are printed out in the default renderer.